# Adding SSD drive to my laptop - presumably impossible?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I read this interesting article on adding SSD drives to laptops:

http://www.pcworld.com/article/239287/ssd_laptop.html

It seems I have no option, since my laptop has only one HD bay and no optical drive.

Is there no option of connecting an SSD drive externally via USB? Not sure if this even exists as a concept but seems viable in principle; would have thought USB3 was fast enough for the job.

But then I'm no hardware ninja!

[EDIT - it's this laptop: [Acer V5 552 (AMD A10 5757M; 6GB)](http://www.pcworld.co.uk/gbuk/laptops-netbooks/laptops/laptops/acer-v5-552-15-6-laptop-iron-21743673-pdt.html)

Comment: You can get an external case with USB3.0 and SATA connector on the inside, and as long as the SSD also uses SATA connector, then yes you can use the USB3.0 SSD drive as an external drive. If you're thinking to boot from the SSD, it is probably better to remove your current HDD, and replace it completely with SSD.

Comment: How about a hybrid drive? It's a small SSD coupled with a larger HDD all in an existing 2.5" drive and frequently used files are cached to the SSD. It's not as fast as a pure SSD, but faster than a HDD and get the benefit of loads of storage.

Comment: @Darius - thanks, that basically answers my question. Richard - yeah I have been looking at hybrids, but I didn't know whether this "half way house" was worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your normal HDD with an SSD and *then* use a external HDD for normal data that can be accessed slower. I would suggest you can buy a USB3 external HDD.
If you post details of your Laptop model, preferably with a link to its specification sheet people could help you more.

Comment: Edited to provide spec details. Thanks for answer.